# Unexpected behavior of vectors when using references

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm creating a game with SDL that usually use events and I've always encountered this weird behavior of vector, and I assume that it is due to the use of reference because I'm more likely to do a pass by reference.

**game.cpp**

```
Events e;
SDL_Event sdle;

// Loop until someone hits the main switch
while (SWITCH)
{
    // Poll events
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&sdle) != 0)
    {
        // Execute event callbacks
        e.exec_events(sdle); // DEBUG BREAKPOINT HERE
    }
}
```

**events.h**

```
struct Listener
{
    SDL_Rect* rect;

    std::function<void()> on_clicked;
    std::function<void()> on_mouse_over;
    std::function<void()> on_mouse_out;
};

Listener l;
SDL_Rect rect = { 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT };
l.rect = &rect;
l.on_mouse_over = []() {
    Game::showerrmsg("Hovered!", "Hovered!");
};
e.add_listener(&l);
```

**events.cpp**

```
std::vector<Listener*> listeners;

// I've passed the sdle here
void Events::exec_events(SDL_Event& e)
{
    analyze(e);
}

// from exec_events, sdle will be passed here
void Events::analyze(SDL_Event& e)
{
    // The problem starts here after hitting the above line
    switch (e.type)
    {
    case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
        currentEvent = MOUSE_MOVE;
        break;
    case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        currentEvent = MOUSE_CLICK;
        break;
    case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        currentEvent = MOUSE_CLICKED;
        break;
    }

    // .......
}
```

**DEBUG POINT:**

Before hitting `switch (e.type)`

[image: normal]
After hitting `switch (e.type)`

### [image: unexpected]

Looks like the objects were deallocated. I don't know what happened

I've tried allocating the listeners vector in the heap but still I got the same problem. Finally, I used pass by reference with pointers and it worked, it didn't mess up the vector. I can't explain this, and ended up asking myself, are pointers better than references (I know pointers are powerful), are references more dangerous than pointers?

Comment: Where are you allocating the listeners?

Comment: I've updated my question **events.h**

Comment: can you change the struct to use a SDL_Rect instead of a SDL_Rect*? And what is the memory footprint if you pass by value to add_listener?

Comment: It's working now, but I'm confused. Why should I do all of them by value, is it because it was overriden by other variables or pointers?

Comment: it's a matter of design. Use the heap only if necessary

Comment: as I said in a previous comment memory footprint could be a consideration but when it comes to lifetimes you are better off using smart pointers or keeping data as local as possible

Answer (score 1):

A vector of references will not work. The contents of a vector should be [assignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable) and references are not.

So your attempt at using pointers overcomes the problem but that's laden with problems as well. What would happen if the pointers are deallocated somewhere else? Consider using smart pointers

> are references more dangerous than pointers?

**update**

Well raw pointers are dangerous. And that's why you should consider using [Smart Pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)

But I wouldn't recommend allocating your vector on the heap. Is your app multithreaded? Would it be thread safe?

Comment: But declaring vector of references will be compile time error itself and it seems OP is dealing with runtime error

Comment: Nobody said the OP is declaring a vector of references

Comment: The OP has chosen to use the vector as a vector of references

Comment: References are not pointers. He's mixing concepts, and that's the heart of the problem here.

Comment: When I used references, they're kinda messing the contents inside that vector. I couldn't agree with that because `SDL_Event& e` has nothing to do with the listeners vector.

Answer (score 0):

### are references more dangerous than pointers?

No, in some over simplification these are the same where the pointers can be changed while the reference can't be changed.

There are some other differences as it is undefined behavior to use a nullptr for references.

It is also not specified how the reference needs to be represented. So this can't be used to be binary compatible.

In case a reference suffice, I don't see a reason to not use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd overcome the problem by replacing `Listeners*` with `Listeners`

```
typedef std::map<str, Listener> listeners_map;
listeners_map listeners;
```